# Make missing separator issue

Tags: makefile

Getting this error `makefile:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.` on this file

```
PROC=findcrypt
O1=consts
O2=sparse
!include ..\plugin.mak
# MAKEDEP dependency list ------------------
$(F)consts$(O)  : $(I)llong.hpp $(I)pro.h consts.cpp findcrypt.hpp
$(F)findcrypt$(O): $(I)area.hpp $(I)bytes.hpp $(I)fpro.h $(I)funcs.hpp               \
          $(I)help.h $(I)ida.hpp $(I)idp.hpp $(I)kernwin.hpp        \
          $(I)lines.hpp $(I)llong.hpp $(I)loader.hpp $(I)moves.hpp  \
          $(I)nalt.hpp $(I)name.hpp $(I)netnode.hpp $(I)pro.h       \
          $(I)segment.hpp $(I)sistack.hpp $(I)ua.hpp $(I)xref.hpp   \
          findcrypt.cpp findcrypt.hpp
$(F)sparse$(O)  : $(I)llong.hpp $(I)pro.h findcrypt.hpp sparse.cpp
```

I've tried using `cat -e -t -v makefile` to identify bad tabs but it all looks ok from what i can tell.

Comment: Is that the entire makefile? Is line four there the line four in the error? What version of make are you using?

Comment: `!include` is probably not understood by your Make. If you have GNU Make (which the error message seems to suggest), just remove the exclamation mark. ... Oh, and use forward slash as the path separator.

Comment: Yes, its the entire makefile supplies with the source code(http://www.hexblog.com/?p=28). Version is GNU Make 3.81.

Comment: changed the line to `include ../plugin.mak` now getting `makefile:4: ../plugin.mak: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `../plugin.mak'.  Stop.`

Comment: Are you sure ../plugin.mak exists? What is the current directory for make?